# Leer y editar un archivo con os.OpenFile

Tags: archivo, go, procesamiento-de-texto

Hola compañeros tengo un problema en go, este problema consiste en leer y editar un archivo de texto (El rendimiento es crucial).
Este problema lo tengo que solventar en GO y lo que intente fue:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("example.txt", os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error al leer el fichero ", err)
        return
    }
    // Leer el fichero
    var texto string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        texto += scanner.Text() + "\n"
    }
    // Agrego contenido
    texto = "\n-INICIO-\n" + texto + "\n-FIN-\n"
    // Guardar contenido
    _, err = fmt.Fprintln(f, texto)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    f.Close()
}
```

**Esto me dio un fallo:**

El error de mi intento fue que el contenido de mi archivo se concardenó con mi edición y mi objetivo era reemplazar todo el texto.

> RESUMEN: Leerlo una vez, obtener su contenido y remplazarlo.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir?

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano gracias por responder, ya lo aclare un poco mejor.. Es leer el archivo modificarlo  y guardarlo. Con solo una lectura, **sin tener que abrirlo varias veces**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tras leer el fichero no te has reposicionado al inicio antes de escribir:

```
   // Agrego contenido
texto = "\n-INICIO-\n" + texto + "\n-FIN-\n"
// Nos posicionamos al inicio del fichero
_, err = f.Seek(0, 0)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
// Guardar contenido
_, err = fmt.Fprintln(f, texto)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

De todos modos, si no tienes que tratar de ningún modo el contenido, esto debería ser más rápido, sobre todo para ficheros grandes ya que sino no se apreciará diferencia:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Creamos un buffer para el contenido. Tener en cuenta que TODO el contenido
    // del fichero se cargará en memoria!!
    var data []byte
    var err error

    f, err := os.OpenFile("example.txt", os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error al leer el fichero ", err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    // Leer el fichero
    if data, err = ioutil.ReadAll(f); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error leyendo fichero: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Agrego contenido
    data = append([]byte("\n-INICIO-\n"), data...)
    data = append(data, []byte("\n-FIN-\n")...)

    // Nos posicionamos al inicio del fichero
    _, err = f.Seek(0, 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // Guardar contenido
    _, err = f.Write(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, no lo comente anteriormente pero me fue de mucha alluda